# Just how transparent are CDOs?

Tags: structured-finance

Not sure if this belongs here on on money SE. 
Just how transparent are CDOs? Would the ultimate investor have insight into the underlying collaterals or just an overall tranche rating? Has transparency changed since the financial crisis ?